# Wiring a light switch

Tags: electrical

I am trying to install a new single pole light switch in a restroom.  I previously had a push button switch that has an off, light, heater, and fan button's and also a light to show when the heater is on.  When I pulled it out there were wires everywhere I cut all wires to switch.  I have 3 black wires, 3 white, and 3 ground.  I have no clue what to do.  I think the hot wire black goes to the bottom screw of the switch once I locate it. Most of the grounds are connected to the box except one that is connected to a neutral wire...Does anyone have a clue what I am talking about? Do I connect the black wire going to the ceiling light to the top screw of the switch?  What about the grounds do I need one to the switch or is the box grounded enough?  Do I connect all neutral white wire together?  Help Me!

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box?

Comment: It sounds like you originally had light, heater, fan controlled independently. Is that what you want to have now? Or just light? Or 2 out of 3? It also sounds like you have 3 cables coming in to the box, which would typically be for "power in" + 2 separate devices (e.g., light, heater) out, not 3.

Comment: Yes, sir, you are correct.  I just want the light to operate off switch no heater fan light combo this time doing away with that going with the no bulb changing LED.  Ok was not sure were the third set of wires came into play you are saying one controlled the light and probably one went to the heater and fan??? That would make sense so I would eliminate that set of wires totally is that correct?  Would not need that extra wiring for new light fixture.

Comment: I have a metter I can find the hot wire and that one would connect to the bottom screw of switch if I am correct.  Then the black wire from the ceiling light would connect to the top screw of switch?  The neutral wires would be omitted I assume and do I need to groud the switch as well or is the box being already grounded sufficent enough for this purpose?

Comment: Neutrals together. Grounds together. If switch has a ground screw (green) then connect that to the other grounds. I would cap (wire nut) the unused black/white on both ends (inside box and in the ceiling).

Comment: Thank you manassehkatz that's a 10-4 now how do you run an outlet off that switch?

Comment: That depends. Do you mean (a) an outlet next to the switch turned on/off with the switch, (b) an outlet turned on/off with the switch for the light fixture in the ceiling, or (c) an unswitched outlet in the same box as the switch?

Comment: prefer C, please

Comment: Not sure who answered my last question but everything is working well I appreciate everyone's help...Mr. manassehkatz and Mr Harper are either or both of you on Facebook?  If so would love to add you both to my friends list you both have been a great help!  Just provide me with a Facebook screen name so I can find you I am also James M. Munro on Facebook...

Comment: @JamesM.Munro You're welcome. I don't do Facebook (Harper might, I have no idea) or any other regular Social Media. Welcome to DIY. Be sure to [take the Tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour). The way we thank people here is by Accepting Answers (checkmark) and Upvotes.

Comment: Well, I truly thank you both for your help.  I will bookmark this page and visited you guys in the future with my Home Improvement projects this is a great page we are thankful for people like you that can give there time and advice to do it yourselfers without costing us an arm and a leg the cost of materials now days is enough expense to a homeowner...God bless

Comment: @JamesM.Munro if you'll take the [tour], you'll see that the preferred way of saying "thank you" is giving a vote to the answer(s) that helped you, then a check mark to the one that helped the most. As an added bonus, others will know that this question has a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, you want to install an unswitched outlet next to the switch. Since you have confirmed that you have neutral in the box, that should be straightforward:

- Unless the circuit is already GFCI protected, you **MUST** use a GFCI receptacle. The following is based on a typical GFCI receptacle.
- Add two pigtails on the **incoming hot** wire with a wire nut. Connect one to the switch (where the incoming hot was previously connected) and one to the **hot** screw on the **LINE** side of the receptacle.
- Add a pigtail to the **neutral bunch** and connect it to the **neutral** screw on the **LINE** side of the receptacle.
- Add a ground wire to the rest of grounds and connect it to the ground screw on the receptacle.

Nothing goes on the **LOAD side**. Those terminals are covered with tape, leave the tape on there, it will save you unlimited grief.

Comment: Nothing goes on the LOAD side.  Those terminals are covered with tape, leave the tape on there,  it will save you unlimited grief.

Comment: @Harper Added to answer.